# How can you evaluate this excel expression?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying evaluate the following expression in Excel:

```
IF(A2:C6="apple",ROW(A2:C6)-ROW(A2)+1,ROW(C6)+1),2)
```

If `apple` is contained within the array, the if condition would return

```
ROW(A2:C6)-ROW(A2)+1
```

and

```
ROW(A2:C6) = 2
```

so

```
ROW(A2:C6)-ROW(A2)+1 = 2-2+1 = 1
```

If the condition evaluates to False, it would return

```
ROW(C6)+1 = 6+1 = 7
```

I am trying to get the formulas from [this site](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/671412-vlookup-second-value.html) to work.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: The `,2)` shouldn't be there. The post in the forum you linked has `SMALL()` which takes the value of `,2)` but which isn't needed in this `IF()` statement. Your `IF()` won't work anyway like this because `A2:C6="apple"` cannot be evaluated as is.

Comment: `ROW(A2:C6) = 2 ` is false because this was meant as an array formula, and `ROW(A2:C6)` would return the Row of the cell that returns true to being equal to `apple`. The `-ROW(A2)+1` is to account for the headers a column might have. so that that the array will NOT return the Row of the worksheet, but how many rows Down from `A2` the match is. And then when no matches it will simply return a default value, most likely c7 is a blank cell, but they use it as C6+1 for drag down and readability.

Comment: @Jerry - A2:C6="apple" is fine - it returns an "array" as per my answer

Comment: @barryhoudini Uh ? Shouldn't COUNTIF be used in cases like this ? Just asking.

Comment: @barryhoudini I was just reading your answer. Thanks for the pointers, I didn't know that ^^ I'm just getting used to handling arrays like this in excel

Comment: Also this is NOT a good question for SO, this is not pertaining to anything with programming, you would be better asking your question either at SuperUser, or on the forum that the formula came from

Comment: @MarcelloRomani There are often multiple ways of getting to the right answer. To me, the OP was looking for the method provided by the link, hence the array formulas.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani - yes COUNTIF is better if you just want to count "apple"s in a range.....but the point here is not to count them but to return an array which contains the rows where the "apple"s reside - and that in turn allows you to get the 1st, 2nd, 3rd occurrence etc. and extract values from another column that correspond to those

Answer (score 3):

The IF expression returns an "array" of values

`=IF(A2:C6="apple",ROW(A2:C6)-ROW(A2)+1,ROW(C6)+1)`

For every cell in A2:C6 that contains "apple" the relative row number is returned, e,g, if Apple is in A2 then 1 is returned, if Apple is in A3 2 is returned etc. If "apple" isn't in any cell then the default value ROW(C6)+1 is returned, so, for example - if "Apple" is only in A3 and C6 you'd get this result returned by the above

`{7,7,7;2,7,7;7,7,7;7,7,7;7,7,5}`

You can see that by putting the formula in a cell then pressing F2 followed by F9

The FALSE part of the formula isn't normally required - this will suffice

`=IF(A2:C6="apple",ROW(A2:C6)-ROW(A2)+1)`

then FALSE values return FALSE.....which is ignored by SMALL anyway

...so a better formula would be something like this:

`=INDEX(B2:B6,SMALL(IF(A2:A6="apple",ROW(A2:A6)-ROW(A2)+1),2))`

That will give you the corresponding value in B2:B6 for the 2nd row with "Apple" in A2:A6 - there's no need to look at A2:C6 when the fruits are only within the first column - this is an "array formula" which needs to be confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

Comment: +1 Also, the F2+F9 is a cool feature!

Comment: @user2371290 your comment appears to be incomplete can you clarify??

Comment: How does the program account for the fact that it returns the quantity for the row when apple occurs the second time ? If I use =IF(A2:C6="apple", "Bob", "Peter") , shouldn`t the formula return Bob  ?